# Getting null POST parameters in a RESTful webservice with symfony 1.4

Tags: php, rest, symfony1

I managed to make a bunch of webservices with symfony using GET parameters, but i need to use POST parameters for a signup webservice.

But when I try to get those POST parameters, for example `$request->getParameter('test');`, they just return a null value.

How comes ?

**EDIT**

Here's a straightforward exemple

testSuccess.json.php

```
{
   "test": <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>
}
```

action.class.php

```
public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request) {
   $this->test = $request->getParameter('test');
}
```

[image: And here's the result]

Answer (score 1):

That would indicate that there isn't a POST parameter called 'email' sent with your request. Apart from that there's not much anyone else can say about your problem without additional information.

Comment: I am not sure. I think there is something you are overlooking outside what we know from your question. There is no reason why $request->getParameter('test') would not return the value of a POST parameter called 'test'. Are you sure this is what's actually happening with this exact example?

Also as a tip you don't need to create a template for a JSON result, for this example, in executeTest() you could do:

return $this->renderText(json_encode(array('test' => $request->getParameter('test'))));

Comment: What else could it be ?
My Restclient plugin ?
My routing ?

Comment: Try return $this->renderText(json_encode($request->getPostParameters()));

Comment: Then it's likely the REST client. Try  'return $this->renderText(json_encode($_POST));' to be sure

Comment: I tried on Restclient and Poster on firefox, both displays the same results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4069/discussion-between-gerry-and-korangar)

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem. It seems that when one does not use

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

these parameters are not available in Symfony. I cannot find anything in the http documentation that dictates this content type for these methods. I have created a [symfony_ticket](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9969) for this bug.

So, to fix your issue add this Content-Type header to your request.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around the issue with the POST parameters being lost with JSON object posts. Instead of using the various parameter methods you need to use the:

`$request->getContent()`

Which shows the JSON as a string within the body of the post. Having the content set as application/json, Symfony effectively ignores the content so doesn't pickup the parameters in the body.